# How to dynamically scroll RecyclerView to keep the last item's bottom edge visible when it changes height?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an Android application that uses RecyclerView, and I want to be able to dynamically scroll the RecyclerView to ensure that the bottom edge of the last item remains visible when its height changes.

I have tried a few approaches, such as using addOnLayoutChangeListener to listen for height changes of the last item and scrolling to the last item using the scrollToPosition method. However, I have encountered some issues. Firstly, I want to cancel the automatic scrolling logic when I manually scroll the RecyclerView and the bottom edge of the last item gets obscured. Secondly, I would like my implementation to handle edge cases, such as when there is only one item in the RecyclerView or when the height change of the last item is minimal.

I'm looking for a concise and clear solution that meets my requirements and handles edge cases. I would greatly appreciate any code examples or insights. Thank you!

```
private val scrollChangeListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            if (!chat_list_rv.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                eventListener?.onSendEvent(LoadNewerEvent())
            }
            val layoutManager = chat_list_rv.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
            val lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
            val itemCount = layoutManager.itemCount

            if (lastVisibleItemPosition == itemCount - 1) {
                val lastVisibleItemView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisibleItemPosition)
                val lastVisibleItemBottom = lastVisibleItemView?.bottom ?: 0
                val recyclerViewBottom = recyclerView.bottom

                if (lastVisibleItemBottom <= recyclerViewBottom) {
                    
                    lastVisibleItemView?.doOnLayout {
                        val newLastVisibleItemBottom = lastVisibleItemView.bottom
                        val newRecyclerViewBottom = recyclerView.bottom

                        if (newLastVisibleItemBottom > newRecyclerViewBottom) {
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, newRecyclerViewBottom - newLastVisibleItemBottom)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it didn't work

Comment: Why height of a recyclerview should be dynamic? You mean a recyclerview inside a bottomsheet for example?

Comment: Have you tried setting `bottom padding` and `cliptopadding=false`?